# NSHTTPURLRequest can't read statusCode

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, http

Just doing a normal HTTP post with a NSMutableURLRequest and sendAsynchronousRequest. But the NSHTTPURLResponse object I pass in has a statusCode of zero after the call. I get this error:

> sendAsynchronousRequest error = Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
>   Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo=0xb374a00
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=`http://54.221.224.251`,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=`http://54.221.224.251`, NSLocalizedDescription=The
>   network connection was lost., NSUnderlyingError=0xb587990 "The network
>   connection was lost."} 2013-09-04 16:46:19.146 panic[2032:5907]
>   statusCode: 0

but no status code. Why? The status code the server is sending is 150.

When I POST different data to the server, and don't ask it to return a statusCode, the connection goes smoothly and as expected.

App Code:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (error)
                NSLog(@"sendAsynchronousRequest error = %@", error);
                NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                int code = [httpResponse statusCode];
                NSString *coder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",code];
                NSLog(@"%@",coder);


            if (data) {
                NSLog(@"This is Data: %@",data);
                NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                int code = [httpResponse statusCode];
                NSString *coder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",code];
                NSLog(@"%@",coder);
            }
        }];
```

PHP Code:

index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/main.php';
class dumb {
function dumber(){
/*--------------------------------------------------
    Handle visits with a login token. If it is
    valid, log the person in.
---------------------------------------------------*/


if(isset($_GET['tkn'])){

    // Is this a valid login token?
    $user = User::findByToken($_GET['tkn']);

    if($user){

        // Yes! Login the user and redirect to the protected page.

        $user->login();
        redirect('panic://success');
    }

    // Invalid token. Redirect back to the login form.
    redirect('panic://fail');
}



/*--------------------------------------------------
    Handle logging out of the system. The logout
    link in protected.php leads here.
---------------------------------------------------*/


if(isset($_GET['logout'])){

    $user = new User();

    if($user->loggedIn()){
        $user->logout();
    }

    redirect('index.php');
}


/*--------------------------------------------------
    Don't show the login page to already 
    logged-in users.
---------------------------------------------------*/


$user = new User();

if($user->loggedIn()){
    redirect('protected.php');
}



/*--------------------------------------------------
    Handle submitting the login form via AJAX
---------------------------------------------------*/

        if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["phash"])){
            rate_limit($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

            rate_limit_tick($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_POST['email']);

            $message = '';
            $name = $_POST["name"];
            $email = $_POST["email"];
            $phash = $_POST["phash"];
            $subject = 'Your Login Link';

            if(!User::exists($email)){
                $subject = "Thank You for Registering!";
                $message = "Thank you for registering at our site!\n\n";
                // Attempt to login or register the person
            $user = User::loginOrRegister($email, $name, $phash);


            $message.= "You can login from this URL:\n";
            $message.= get_page_url()."?tkn=".$user->generateToken()."\n\n";

            $message.= "The link is going expire automatically after 10 minutes.";

            $result = send_email($fromEmail, $_POST['email'], $subject, $message);

            if(!$result){
            sendResponse(403, 'Error Sending Email');
            return false;
            }
            }
        else{
                sendResponse(150, 'Account already created.');
                return false;
        }
        }
        else if(isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["phash"])){
            rate_limit($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

            rate_limit_tick($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_POST['email']);

            $message = '';
            $name = '';
            $email = $_POST["email"];
            $phash = $_POST["phash"];
            $subject = 'Your Login Link';

            if(!User::exists($email)){
                sendResponse(155, 'Account not yet created.');
                return false;
            }
            else{
            // Attempt to login or register the person
            $user = User::loginOrRegister($email, $name, $phash);


            $message.= "You can login from this URL:\n";
            $message.= get_page_url()."?tkn=".$user->generateToken()."\n\n";

            $message.= "The link is going expire automatically after 10 minutes.";

            $result = send_email($fromEmail, $_POST['email'], $subject, $message);

            if(!$result){
            sendResponse(403, 'Error Sending Email');
            return false;
            }
        }
        }

/*--------------------------------------------------
    Output the login form
---------------------------------------------------*/
}
}
$api = new dumb;
$api->dumber();
?>
```

sendResponse function

```
function sendResponse($status, $body = '', $content_type = 'text/html')
{
    $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . 'ERROR';
    header($status_header);
    header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);
    echo $body;
}
```

Comment: The error message very much indicates that you lost the connection - even before you got any status back. Looks like a server issue, right?

Comment: Ill post the server code now.

Comment: And maybe the request as well...

Comment: You must have NSHTTPURLResponse to see the status. So, if there is no intenet connection or cannot send the request to server, by no means will you get any response. So, you will end up with (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)aConn didFailWithError:(NSError *)error.

Comment: @insane-36 So would this not work? Considering I'm asking for the NSHTTPURLResponse status code after connection?

Comment: Well if you get the response from the server only then it would work. Then you could read the status code such as 401, 404, 500 from the server. But, if you do not have internet connection, you have no way to see the response. Put debug point in  connection:didReceiveResponse: delegate method and see if it actually went to the server.

Comment: I put a breakpoint in at connection:didReceiveResponse in NSURLConnection.h, but it never hit the breakpoint, and I still received the same error as above.

Comment: Not sure how to see if it went to the server tho...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1xx status codes are special (see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-23.html#status.1xx); also, it's not a good idea just to make up new status codes.